# Ubuntu 12.04 boot up is unreasonably slow

Tags: unity, 12.04, boot, grub2, partitioning

One of the things I like about Ubuntu is the allegedly fast boot time, unfortunately that's not the case for me anymore.

On my computer Ubuntu itself boots up in forty seconds (from choosing Ubuntu in the grub menu to reaching the login screen), and my user boots up in in almost **fifty seconds** (from entering my password to the appearance of the Dash).

I want to note that although I never had fast boot-ups in Ubuntu, (the boot of Ubuntu itself was always slow), since the last upgrade things have just gotten worse.
I also want to note that after the boot itself my Ubuntu runs quite smooth almost without any lag.

Some hardware details:

- Memory: 2.0 GiB
- Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz × 2
- Graphics: GeForce 7100 GS/PCIe/SSE2
- I have both Ubuntu and Windows XP with dual boot, each installed on a different disk. My Ubuntu runs on an healthy 500 GB WDC Hard Disk with average read time of 108 Mb/s. My partitions can be seen in the following image:
  [image]

Does anyone have any idea what makes my computer boot slowly, is my hardware outdated? Did I make any crucial mistake with the partitions when I first set Ubuntu up?

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: I have PC with lower hardware specs and it works with no problem. try to reinstall your Ubuntu and see if it helps

Answer (score 4):

I think for that processor it is not all that slow.  You could try [boot chart](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting) to see if it tells you anything useful.

Comment: Can I post the boot chart on Ask Ubuntu, or does it contain any personal information?

Comment: @eladrich It shouldn't. If it does, we'll edit it out.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a downgrade to 10.04, that was the last version I used that was really known for boot speed (and your hardware seems suited for it). It is not at all uncommon for a decrease in boot speed in 12.04.

Comment: I don't see myself going back to gnome 2 after using Unity for two years, and even if I did 10.04 won't be supported for long.

Comment: 10.04 will still be `usable` for quite some time (just look at XP). You probably cannot expect a significant improvement on this matter from any release post-10.10, given the same hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Wubi ? if you are using Wubi and Installed the Upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 then you need a clean Install.

Comment: I'm not using Wubi, I installed Ubuntu on a different disk using a CD.

Answer (score 0):

My Ubuntu 12.04 booted also unreasonably slowly. I solved the problem by editing `/etc/fstab` file. I changed the last entry on Windows partition line to 0. After this the computer boots as quickly as during earlier versions of Ubuntu.

The problem which caused the slow down was the Windows filesystem check. Putting the value of the last column to zero, prevents checking.

Answer (score -4):

I had a similar problem, and someone on a forum suggested this could be due to CD drives with CD's in them (even though the CD's are not themselves being booted).

That fixed my problem--with a CD in, my system boots quickly. You might try this.